# Реализация автозаполнения

Tags: php, автоматизация, javascript

Добрый день. Есть веб приложение на php. Так же есть форма добавления записей к базе.

Задача: реализовать автозаполнение в форме вода.
Т.е. если вводится там какое либо значение по введеным ранее данным предлагать варианты дополнения.

Примерно как [тут](http://devzone.zend.com/images/articles/4229/image3.gif)

Просьба подсказать как такое реализовать? Есть ли готовые решения?

Comment: $10 (час работы)

зы: какой вопрос - такой ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- [Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)
- [Автозаполнение](http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/%D0%90%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)
- [jQuery AutoComplete](http://habrahabr.ru/post/74713/)

Гугл нынче не актуален?